# mysql: two table join with sum

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to join two tables and also get a SUM and flailing badly.  I need to get the total commission amounts for each affiliate where affiliate.approved=1 AND order.status=3.

```
//affiliate table
affiliate_id | firstname | lastname | approved |
     1            joe        shmoe       1
     2           frank       dimag       0
     3            bob        roosky      1
```

here's the order table

```
//order
affiliate_id | order_status_id | commission
    1                3              0.20
    1                0              0.30
    2                3              0.10
    3                3              0.25
    1                3              0.25
    2                3              0.15
    2                0              0.20
```

and here's what I'd like the query to return:

```
affiliate_id | commission
    1             0.45
    3             0.25
```

Here is my attempt that doesn't work.  It outputs just one line.

```
 SELECT order.affiliate_id, SUM(order.commission) AS total, affiliate.firstname, affiliate.lastname FROM `order`, `affiliate` WHERE order.order_status_id=3 AND affiliate.approved=1 AND order.affiliate_id = affiliate.affiliate_id ORDER BY total;
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed `GROUP BY`, try this:

```
SELECT 
      `order`.affiliate_id,
      SUM(`order`.commission) AS total,
      affiliate.firstname,
      affiliate.lastname
FROM `order` 
JOIN `affiliate` 
ON `order`.order_status_id = 3 AND affiliate.approved = 1 AND `order`.affiliate_id = affiliate.affiliate_id
GROUP BY `order`.affiliate_id
ORDER BY total;
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8da776/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Query for your solution :-

```
   SELECT order.affiliate_id, SUM(order.commission) AS total,affiliate.firstname,
  affiliate.lastname 
    FROM `order`, `affiliate`
    WHERE order.order_status_id=3 
    AND affiliate.approved=1 
    AND order.affiliate_id = affiliate.affiliate_id 
    GROUP BY order.affiliate_id
    ORDER BY total;
```

Answer (score 0):

**First:** Remove the implicit `join` syntax. It's confusing.

**Second:** You needed to group by `affiliate_id`. Using aggregate function without group by collapses your result set into a single row.

Here's the query using `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    `order`.affiliate_id,
    SUM(`order`.commission) AS total,
    affiliate.firstname,
    affiliate.lastname
FROM `order`
INNER JOIN`affiliate` ON  `order`.affiliate_id = affiliate.affiliate_id
WHERE `order`.order_status_id = 3
AND affiliate.approved = 1
GROUP BY affiliate.affiliate_id
ORDER BY total;
```

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fbbb/2/0)</kbd>

**Caution:** You have picked one of the reserved words of MySQL as table name (`order`). Be aware to enclose it with (`)backtick always .

<sub>Just a gentle reminder</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
select affiliate.affiliate_id,sum(`order`.commission) as total from affiliate left join `order` on affiliate.affiliate_id=`order`.affiliate_id
where affiliate.approved=1 and `order`.order_status_id=3 group by affiliate.affiliate_id
```

In addition,"order" is a key word of SQL , I recommend you not to use it as a table/column name.